# What is the meaning of tagging in web services?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, tagging

I know and I have worked on tagging in blog posts..etc I just saw a paper which says how to automate tagging in web services. But what do you exactly mean by tagging in case of web services?

Comment: sry. I already found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A tag is a non-hierarchical keyword or term assigned to a piece
  of information.
- This kind of metadata gives a brief description of web services
  and makes users find proper services more easily, categorize
  web services and make web services management more
  effective.
- Tags allow cross-browsing between documents.
- Tags can be used as keywords for search engines and this is
  helpful to improve the performance of search engines.
- Tags can also be used as a feature in query expansion systems
  and recommendation systems.